# Случайно удалил postgres'у superuser, теперь не знаю как его вернуть, есть варианты решения проблемы?

Tags: postgresql

вот какую ошибку мне выдает pgadmin4[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть похожая проблема:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61784
Попробуйте этот вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

Останови постгрис, запусти его в режиме single-user mode (`--single`), в этом режиме юзер всегда считается суперюзером, восстанови права и запусти постгрис в обычном режиме.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER